# Catch spellcheck correction event in a span element

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm working with the New York Times ICE Editor. It's a track changes tool developed in JavaScript. We've recently encountered a bug that if there is a misspelling in text, and you select a correction via the right click context menu, the correction is not annotated in any way (blue text that represents an addition). The reason behind this is that there is no plumbing in place to catch any events and tell the ICE Editor to annotate the new text.

The annotations are written as "span" elements that have jQuery events bound to them. When a user hits a key, the text is updated via key down/up events.

With the spell checker, there is no "spell check correction" event that I can find that you can attach to a span element, and that would really help me out here. Is there anything out there? I've started looking at the MutationObserver to try to detect if the DOM changes, but I want to know if there's anything better. With the MutationObserver I've got a feeling that I'm going to have to jump through a number of hoops to make this work.